# I am trying to screen scrape the Date and GDPnow number from the Atlanta Fed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

https://www.atlantafed.org/cqer/research/gdpnow

I am trying to screen scrape the current GDPnow number with the date from the Atlanta Fed. Currently "Latest estimate: 3.5 percent — January 20, 2023." I then want to take the GDP number and the date and add it to my existing DF.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://www.atlantafed.org/cqer/research/gdpnow"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.atlantafed.org/cqer/research/gdpnow'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
x = soup.select_one('#Slot').get_text()
gdp, date = re.search(r'(?sm)(-?\d+\.\d*).*—\s*(.*?)\s*$', x).groups()
print(gdp)
print(date)
```

Prints:

```
3.5
January 20, 2023
```